# Wiring an Event to the Red X on a WindowStyle.ToolWindow

Tags: caliburn.micro

I have a UserControl that I am showing with the ShowDialog method of the WindowManager. The User Control has two buttons (Ok, Cancel) as well as some input.

I would like to also run some code when the User selects the red X in the upper right of the Window. Is there a way to wire an event to that with Caliburn Micro?

Thanks

Chuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done something similar with the `ShowWindow`method from the `WindowManager`, the `ShowDialog` method should work in the same way when you're passing a `ViewModel` (which I'm assuming you're doing in this case).

It's worth reading [this page](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Screens,%20Conductors%20and%20Composition) in the documentation for a more complete explanation, but essentially a `Screen` has a `CanClose` method, which you can override with custom behaviour.

> CanClose – The default implementation always allows closing. Override
>   this method to add custom guard logic.

So, within the `ViewModel` class that you're passing to `ShowDialog`, you could do something like:

```
public override void CanClose(Action<bool> callback)
{
    bool canClose = false;

    // if (yourConditionHere)
        canClose = true;

    callback(closeDialog);
}
```

Where `canClose` could just as easily be a private field updated elsewhere in the class.

Comment: This is very similar to the approach I decided to take. I wanted to make sure that I was not missing something. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: That's certainly the way I've done it in the past, hopefully it's the most logical =D